# Grabbing Contents from File in PHP and then Converting Then into Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am storing all of data from each of the folders inside of "Test" inside of a array unsorted because it will be simpler for me later to do it this way. Once I have the array of string all set I echo it to the JavaScript where it is being processed to arrays inside of a array. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am getting hundreds of errors. The main on is the path for "Test" in the PHP is incorrect because it looks for /Test/data.txt and /Test/properties.txt not /Test/(Folder inside of "Test")/data.txt and /Test/(Folder inside of "Test")/properties.txt. Thank you all in advance.

```
<?php
//Gets the path to the directory "Test" on the desktop
$userHome = realpath("./../../../../")."\\Desktop\\Test";

//Gets the name of all of the files inside of "Test"
$testFolderArray = array_diff(scandir($userHome), array("..", "."));

//Creates the arrays that will be exported
$dataArray = array();
$propertiesArray = array();

//For each value inside of test it runs this loop
foreach($x = 0; $x < count($testFolderArray); $x++) {

//Creates the path to the "data.txt" and "properties.txt" inside of each folder inside of the directory "test"
$dataFile = $userHome.$testFolderArray[$x]."\\data.txt";
$propertiesFile = $userHome.$testFolderArray[$x]."\\properties.txt";


//Reads the data inside of those files
$data = file_get_contents($dataFile);
$properties = file_get_contents($propertiesFile);

$dataArray[$x] = $data;
$propertiesArray[$x] = $properties;
}
/*
* By this point $dataArray and $propertiesArray should contain all of the information of all the files inside of the folders inside of "Test"
*
*/
?>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Should be exact copies of $dataArray and $propertiesArray
    var data = '<?php echo json_encode($dataArray);?>';
    var properties = '<?php echo json_encode($dataArray);?>';

    //Where the sorted array wil be stored
    var dataSorted = new Array();
    var propertiesSorted = new Array();

    //Run for each index of data inside of "data"
    for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++){
    //Put tempArray inside the array dataSorted
        var tempArray = data.split(",");
        dataSorted[x] = tempArray;

    }

    //Run for each index of data inside of "properties"
    for(var x = 0; x < properties.length; x++){
    //Puts tempArray inside the array propertiesArry
        var tempArray = properties.split(",");
        propertiesSorted[x] = tempArray;
    }

    //By this point dataSorted and propertiesSorted should consist of arrays.

</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the errors? Are php or js errors?

Comment: : file_get_contents(C:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\Test\data.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\PHP\wamp\www\StackOverFlow_Question.php on line 20

Comment: Well and what do you make of this message? "C:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\Test\data.txt ... No such file or directory"?

Comment: The issue is that it should something like C:\Users\ltrujillo\Desktop\Test\SubFolder\data.txt

Answer (score 0):

I admit I did not read all your code, but here are two mistakes, I guess:

```
var data = '<?php echo json_encode($dataArray);?>';
var properties = '<?php echo json_encode($dataArray);?>';
```

1. properties = ... $dataArray: shouldn't that be $propertiesArray?
2. You encode the PHP array as JSON an after that you enter it as a Javascript-String. You should remove the quotation marks like this:

   ```
   var data = <?php echo json_encode($dataArray);?>;
   var properties = <?php echo json_encode($propertiesArray);?>;
   ```

Comment: Yes it should. Thank You. However the errors still prevail.

Comment: No, he cannot use json_encoded string to initialize js array. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This will fail because the json data cannot be used to initialize a Javascript array. You should parse the Jsonified string with JSON.parse(''), supposed that there are not other errors in your logic.

Also, posting errors, or at least tell if are js or php errors could help if there are other errors.

In general, JSON is not a subset of Javascript object...

Comment: I changed it to `var data = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($dataArray);?>');
 var properties = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($propertiesArray);?>');` Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it should me less error prone. You could check if data is really an array with typeof data. I do not know file contents, or paths, so I assume the php part is correct. The error you said about No such file or directory however should be the blocking one. Solve it specifing correct paths, then let's check js part errors.